# spark streaming for long running but i got weird exception on spark with event hub

Tags: events, azure-eventhub

```
I have two spark job for the different tenant, one of spark job has ended up with an exception while receiving data from the event hub.


2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  ReceiveLinkHandler:62 - onLinkRemoteOpen linkName[61c8c1_3f3c_G1_1547190097227], remoteTarget[null], remoteSource[null], action[waitingForError]
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  BaseLinkHandler:42 - onLinkRemoteClose linkName[61c8c1_3f3c_G1_1547190097227], errorCondition[null], errorDescription[null]
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  BaseLinkHandler:68 - processOnClose linkName[61c8c1_3f3c_G1_1547190097227], errorCondition[amqp:unauthorized-access], errorDescription[Unauthorized access. 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net/edgeeventhub/consumergroups/$default/partitions/30'. TrackingId:e5ea01bb7ec44523acf8749ba9203f3c_G1, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2019-01-11T07:01:37]
2019-01-11 01:01:37 WARN  MessageReceiver:406 - clientId[PartitionReceiverImpl8446ec-InternalReceiver], receiverPath[edgeeventhub/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/30], linkName[61c8c1_3f3c_G1_1547190097227], onError: com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.AuthorizationFailedException: Unauthorized access. 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net/edgeeventhub/consumergroups/$default/partitions/30'. TrackingId:e5ea01bb7ec44523acf8749ba9203f3c_G1, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2019-01-11T07:01:37
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  BaseLinkHandler:92 - closeSession for linkName[61c8c1_3f3c_G1_1547190097227], errorCondition[amqp:unauthorized-access], errorDescription[Unauthorized access. 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net/edgeeventhub/consumergroups/$default/partitions/30'. TrackingId:e5ea01bb7ec44523acf8749ba9203f3c_G1, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2019-01-11T07:01:37]
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  BaseLinkHandler:27 - onLinkLocalClose linkName[61c8c1_3f3c_G1_1547190097227], errorCondition[amqp:unauthorized-access], errorDescription[Unauthorized access. 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net/edgeeventhub/consumergroups/$default/partitions/30'. TrackingId:e5ea01bb7ec44523acf8749ba9203f3c_G1, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2019-01-11T07:01:37]
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  SessionHandler:103 - onSessionLocalClose entityName[edgeeventhub/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/30], condition[Error{condition=amqp:unauthorized-access, description='Unauthorized access. 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net/edgeeventhub/consumergroups/$default/partitions/30'. TrackingId:e5ea01bb7ec44523acf8749ba9203f3c_G1, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2019-01-11T07:01:37', info=null}]
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  RetryUtils:54 - failure: checkCursor initial
2019-01-11 01:01:37 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 30.0 in stage 1968.0 (TID 63006)
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.AuthorizationFailedException: Unauthorized access. 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net/edgeeventhub/consumergroups/$default/partitions/30'. TrackingId:e5ea01bb7ec44523acf8749ba9203f3c_G1, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2019-01-11T07:01:37, errorContext[NS: edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net, PATH: edgeeventhub/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/30, REFERENCE_ID: 61c8c1_3f3c_G1_1547190097227, PREFETCH_COUNT: 500, LINK_CREDIT: 0, PREFETCH_Q_LEN: 0]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.ExceptionUtil.completeExceptionally(ExceptionUtil.java:98)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageReceiver.drainPendingReceives(MessageReceiver.java:462)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageReceiver.onError(MessageReceiver.java:447)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageReceiver.onClose(MessageReceiver.java:731)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler.processOnClose(BaseLinkHandler.java:74)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler.handleRemoteLinkClosed(BaseLinkHandler.java:113)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler.onLinkRemoteClose(BaseLinkHandler.java:48)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.handle(BaseHandler.java:176)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:108)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.dispatch(ReactorImpl.java:324)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.process(ReactorImpl.java:291)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessagingFactory$RunReactor.run(MessagingFactory.java:507)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.AuthorizationFailedException: Unauthorized access. 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net/edgeeventhub/consumergroups/$default/partitions/30'. TrackingId:e5ea01bb7ec44523acf8749ba9203f3c_G1, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2019-01-11T07:01:37, errorContext[NS: edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net, PATH: edgeeventhub/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/30, REFERENCE_ID: 61c8c1_3f3c_G1_1547190097227, PREFETCH_COUNT: 500, LINK_CREDIT: 0, PREFETCH_Q_LEN: 0]
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.ExceptionUtil.toException(ExceptionUtil.java:37)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageReceiver.onClose(MessageReceiver.java:730)
        ... 15 more
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  RedisConnector:30 - Connection need to be established with redis.
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  SessionHandler:111 - onSessionRemoteClose entityName[edgeeventhub/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/30], condition[Error{condition=amqp:unauthorized-access, description='Unauthorized access. 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net/edgeeventhub/consumergroups/$default/partitions/30'. TrackingId:e5ea01bb7ec44523acf8749ba9203f3c_G1, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2019-01-11T07:01:37', info=null}]
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  RedisConnector:30 - Connection need to be established with redis.
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  DateUtil$:129 - Inside generate redis key method
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  DateUtil$:130 - Timestamp comming from event hub : 1547186400000
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  DateUtil$:154 - Generated Key : 1234@@@###%%%CrowdCount@@@###%%%1-10-2019@@@###%%%23@@@###%%%
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  DateUtil$:155 - Exit from generate redis key method
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  CrowdCountDaoImpl:225 - CrowdCount Redis key to delete - 1234@@@###%%%CrowdCount@@@###%%%1-10-2019@@@###%%%23@@@###%%%1@@@###%%%2@@@###%%%48
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  CrowdCountDaoImpl:227 - CrowdCount key deleted from redis - 1234@@@###%%%CrowdCount@@@###%%%1-10-2019@@@###%%%23@@@###%%%1@@@###%%%2@@@###%%%48
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  CrowdCountJob:56 - Store count object sends at dao to save in db
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  RedisConnector:30 - Connection need to be established with redis.
2019-01-11 01:01:37 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 30.0 in stage 1968.0 (TID 63006, localhost, executor driver): java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.AuthorizationFailedException: Unauthorized access. 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net/edgeeventhub/consumergroups/$default/partitions/30'. TrackingId:e5ea01bb7ec44523acf8749ba9203f3c_G1, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2019-01-11T07:01:37, errorContext[NS: edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net, PATH: edgeeventhub/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/30, REFERENCE_ID: 61c8c1_3f3c_G1_1547190097227, PREFETCH_COUNT: 500, LINK_CREDIT: 0, PREFETCH_Q_LEN: 0]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.ExceptionUtil.completeExceptionally(ExceptionUtil.java:98)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageReceiver.drainPendingReceives(MessageReceiver.java:462)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageReceiver.onError(MessageReceiver.java:447)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageReceiver.onClose(MessageReceiver.java:731)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler.processOnClose(BaseLinkHandler.java:74)
 at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler.handleRemoteLinkClosed(BaseLinkHandler.java:113)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler.onLinkRemoteClose(BaseLinkHandler.java:48)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.handle(BaseHandler.java:176)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:108)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.dispatch(ReactorImpl.java:324)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.process(ReactorImpl.java:291)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessagingFactory$RunReactor.run(MessagingFactory.java:507)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.AuthorizationFailedException: Unauthorized access. 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net/edgeeventhub/consumergroups/$default/partitions/30'. TrackingId:e5ea01bb7ec44523acf8749ba9203f3c_G1, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2019-01-11T07:01:37, errorContext[NS: edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net, PATH: edgeeventhub/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/30, REFERENCE_ID: 61c8c1_3f3c_G1_1547190097227, PREFETCH_COUNT: 500, LINK_CREDIT: 0, PREFETCH_Q_LEN: 0]
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.ExceptionUtil.toException(ExceptionUtil.java:37)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageReceiver.onClose(MessageReceiver.java:730)
        ... 15 more

2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  CrowdCountServiceImpl:198 - Size of list in redis - 9
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  CrowdCountServiceImpl:203 - Splited key size - 7
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  RedisConnector:30 - Connection need to be established with redis.
2019-01-11 01:01:37 ERROR TaskSetManager:70 - Task 30 in stage 1968.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  CrowdCountServiceImpl:222 - Median value is - 7.0
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  CrowdCountDaoImpl:51 - CrowdCount Data need to be inserted into database
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  TaskSchedulerImpl:54 - Removed TaskSet 1968.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  TaskSchedulerImpl:54 - Cancelling stage 1968
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - ResultStage 1968 (start at EventhubMaster.scala:112) failed in 0.610 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 30 in stage 1968.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 30.0 in stage 1968.0 (TID 63006, localhost, executor driver): java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.AuthorizationFailedException: Unauthorized access. 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net/edgeeventhub/consumergroups/$default/partitions/30'. TrackingId:e5ea01bb7ec44523acf8749ba9203f3c_G1, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2019-01-11T07:01:37, errorContext[NS: edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net, PATH: edgeeventhub/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/30, REFERENCE_ID: 61c8c1_3f3c_G1_1547190097227, PREFETCH_COUNT: 500, LINK_CREDIT: 0, PREFETCH_Q_LEN: 0]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.ExceptionUtil.completeExceptionally(ExceptionUtil.java:98)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageReceiver.drainPendingReceives(MessageReceiver.java:462)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageReceiver.onError(MessageReceiver.java:447)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageReceiver.onClose(MessageReceiver.java:731)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler.processOnClose(BaseLinkHandler.java:74)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler.handleRemoteLinkClosed(BaseLinkHandler.java:113)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler.onLinkRemoteClose(BaseLinkHandler.java:48)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.handle(BaseHandler.java:176)
  at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:108)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.dispatch(ReactorImpl.java:324)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.process(ReactorImpl.java:291)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessagingFactory$RunReactor.run(MessagingFactory.java:507)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.AuthorizationFailedException: Unauthorized access. 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net/edgeeventhub/consumergroups/$default/partitions/30'. TrackingId:e5ea01bb7ec44523acf8749ba9203f3c_G1, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2019-01-11T07:01:37, errorContext[NS: edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net, PATH: edgeeventhub/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/30, REFERENCE_ID: 61c8c1_3f3c_G1_1547190097227, PREFETCH_COUNT: 500, LINK_CREDIT: 0, PREFETCH_Q_LEN: 0]
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.ExceptionUtil.toException(ExceptionUtil.java:37)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageReceiver.onClose(MessageReceiver.java:730)
        ... 15 more

Driver stacktrace:
2019-01-11 01:01:37 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Job 1968 failed: start at EventhubMaster.scala:112, took 0.615351 s
2019-01-11 01:01:37 ERROR StreamExecution:91 - Query [id = a0db89e7-71d2-4b3f-af87-b1d0a1fcdc69, runId = 36bf254b-55e1-4f5a-bc56-70a4543d9767] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 30 in stage 1968.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 30.0 in stage 1968.0 (TID 63006, localhost, executor driver): java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.AuthorizationFailedException: Unauthorized access. 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net/edgeeventhub/consumergroups/$default/partitions/30'. TrackingId:e5ea01bb7ec44523acf8749ba9203f3c_G1, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2019-01-11T07:01:37, errorContext[NS: edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net, PATH: edgeeventhub/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/30, REFERENCE_ID: 61c8c1_3f3c_G1_1547190097227, PREFETCH_COUNT: 500, LINK_CREDIT: 0, PREFETCH_Q_LEN: 0]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.ExceptionUtil.completeExceptionally(ExceptionUtil.java:98)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageReceiver.drainPendingReceives(MessageReceiver.java:462)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageReceiver.onError(MessageReceiver.java:447)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageReceiver.onClose(MessageReceiver.java:731)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler.processOnClose(BaseLinkHandler.java:74)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler.handleRemoteLinkClosed(BaseLinkHandler.java:113)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler.onLinkRemoteClose(BaseLinkHandler.java:48)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.handle(BaseHandler.java:176)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:108)
at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.dispatch(ReactorImpl.java:324)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.process(ReactorImpl.java:291)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessagingFactory$RunReactor.run(MessagingFactory.java:507)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.AuthorizationFailedException: Unauthorized access. 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net/edgeeventhub/consumergroups/$default/partitions/30'. TrackingId:e5ea01bb7ec44523acf8749ba9203f3c_G1, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2019-01-11T07:01:37, errorContext[NS: edgeeventhub.servicebus.windows.net, PATH: edgeeventhub/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/30, REFERENCE_ID: 61c8c1_3f3c_G1_1547190097227, PREFETCH_COUNT: 500, LINK_CREDIT: 0, PREFETCH_Q_LEN: 0]
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.ExceptionUtil.toException(ExceptionUtil.java:37)
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageReceiver.onClose(MessageReceiver.java:730)
        ... 15 more

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)
```

Unauthorized access. 'Send' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://changed-eh-ns.servicebus.windows.net/changed-eh'. TrackingId:7754266cd3f540099b6dda8ee0f66a10_G11,TimeStamp:12/7/2014 7:56:40 AM"

It seems pretty clear that I have some sort of authentication issue, but I've been unable to work out how to resolve it. I am trying to send from a spark job application.

Comment: can someone help our production is shutdown for a while ?  this job running for 10 days ,but this i found the above exception what could be the reason for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the above issue by allowing port 5671 by firewall on Virtual machine where i have deployed spark job.